# How to properly use Dagger scopes in an MVVM project?

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2

I'm creating a simple app and I want to use `Dagger` in it (I'm a complete beginner in `Dagger`). It has three layers: `View`, `ViewModel`, and `Repository`.

Naturally each one of the classes in these layers have different dependencies and different scopes. Take a look at this sample:

```
class SongsFragment : Fragment() {
    val viewModel: SongsViewModel
}

class SongsViewModel(val songRepository: SongRepository) : ViewModel() {

}

class SongRepository(val songDao: SongDao) {

}
```

`SongsViewModel` instance should exist as long as `SongsFragment` exist and `SongRepository` instance should exist as long as `SongsViewModel` instance exists. (Correct me if it's not a good practice)

I'd appreciate a simple example of how to use modules, components (and subcomponents if necessary), and scopes to achieve this goal.

Comment: I published an article about that. You can take a look https://medium.com/@ibrahimsn98/android-mvvm-with-dagger-2-retrofit-rxjava-architecture-components-6f5da1a75135

Comment: Thanks but your article uses classes in dagger-android package and since I'm new to Dagger, I don't want to use them for now.